# NFC Host Card Emulation (HCE) on Android not working on particular devices

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, apdu, hce

I want to develop an Android app in which one device acts as an NFC Tag, and the another mobile device reads it.
I have two android devices, A and B -
The NFC HCE feature works on device A, i.e., emulating the Tag with correct NDEF Data, and Device B can read it. The specs of the NFC Tag (HCE) of Device A are -

[NFC TAG (HCE) SPECS DEVICE A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QHoD.jpg)

But now, when I try to do it with device B, the NDEF data is not written and cannot be read by Device A. The specs of the NFC Tag (HCE) of Device B are -

[NFC TAG (HCE) SPECS DEVICE B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a88gh.jpg)

---

The HostApduService code is as follows -

```
package com.example.cn

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.nfc.NdefMessage
import android.nfc.NdefRecord
import android.nfc.cardemulation.HostApduService
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.util.*

class CardService : HostApduService() {

    private val TAG = "HostApduService"

    private val APDU_SELECT = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
            0xA4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
            0x04.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            0x07.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            0xD2.toByte(),
            0x76.toByte(),
            0x00.toByte(),
            0x00.toByte(),
            0x85.toByte(),
            0x01.toByte(),
            0x01.toByte(), // NDEF Tag Application name
            0x00.toByte()  // Le field  - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
    )

    private val CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
            0xa4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
            0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            0x0c.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            0xe1.toByte(), 0x03.toByte() // file identifier of the CC file
    )

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
            0xb0.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
            0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            0x0f.toByte()  // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    )

    // In the scenario that we have done a CC read, the same byte[] match
    // for ReadBinary would trigger and we don't want that in succession
    private var READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), 0x11.toByte(), // CCLEN length of the CC file
            0x20.toByte(), // Mapping Version 2.0
            0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLe maximum
            0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLc maximum
            0x04.toByte(), // T field of the NDEF File Control TLV
            0x06.toByte(), // L field of the NDEF File Control TLV
            0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), // File Identifier of NDEF file
            0xFF.toByte(), 0xFE.toByte(), // Maximum NDEF file size of 65534 bytes
            0x00.toByte(), // Read access without any security
            0xFF.toByte(), // Write access without any security
            0x90.toByte(), 0x00.toByte() // A_OKAY
    )

    private val NDEF_SELECT_OK = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
            0xa4.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
            0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            0x0c.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte() // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
            0xb0.toByte() // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
            0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
            0x00.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
            0x02.toByte()  // Le field
    )

    private val A_OKAY = byteArrayOf(
            0x90.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
            0x00.toByte()   // SW2  Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val A_ERROR = byteArrayOf(
            0x6A.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
            0x82.toByte()   // SW2  Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val NDEF_ID = byteArrayOf(0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte())

    private var NDEF_URI = NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", "NFC Clock", NDEF_ID))
    private var NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
    private var NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
            BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(), 2
    )


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        if (intent.hasExtra("ndefMessage")) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Set NFC tag as " + intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage"))
            NDEF_URI =
                    NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage"), NDEF_ID))

            NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
            NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
                    BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(), 2
            )
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() | NDEF" + NDEF_URI.records[0].payload);

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray {

        //
        // The following flow is based on Appendix E "Example of Mapping Version 2.0 Command Flow"
        // in the NFC Forum specification
        //
        Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: " + commandApdu.toHex())

        //
        // First command: NDEF Tag Application select (Section 5.5.2 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(APDU_SELECT, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Second command: Capability Container select (Section 5.5.3 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Third command: ReadBinary data from CC file (Section 5.5.4 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(
                        READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER,
                        commandApdu
                ) && !READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK
        ) {
            Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE.toHex()
            )
            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = true
            return READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE
        }

        //
        // Fourth command: NDEF Select command (Section 5.5.5 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(NDEF_SELECT_OK, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_SELECT_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN, commandApdu)) {
            // Build our response
            val response = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + A_OKAY.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, NDEF_URI_LEN.size, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(commandApdu.sliceArray(0..1), NDEF_READ_BINARY)) {
            val offset = commandApdu.sliceArray(2..3).toHex().toInt(16)
            val length = commandApdu.sliceArray(4..4).toHex().toInt(16)

            val fullResponse = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + NDEF_URI_BYTES.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, fullResponse, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(
                    NDEF_URI_BYTES,
                    0,
                    fullResponse,
                    NDEF_URI_LEN.size,
                    NDEF_URI_BYTES.size
            )

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Full data: " + fullResponse.toHex())
            Log.i(TAG, "READ_BINARY - OFFSET: " + offset + " - LEN: " + length)

            val slicedResponse = fullResponse.sliceArray(offset until fullResponse.size)

            // Build our response
            val realLength = if (slicedResponse.size <= length) slicedResponse.size else length
            val response = ByteArray(realLength + A_OKAY.size)

            System.arraycopy(slicedResponse, 0, response, 0, realLength)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, realLength, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        //
        // We're doing something outside our scope
        //
        Log.wtf(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | I don't know what's going on!!!")
        return A_ERROR
    }

    override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: $reason")
    }


    private val HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()

    fun ByteArray.toHex(): String {
        val result = StringBuffer()

        forEach {
            val octet = it.toInt()
            val firstIndex = (octet and 0xF0).ushr(4)
            val secondIndex = octet and 0x0F
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[firstIndex])
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[secondIndex])
        }

        return result.toString()
    }

    fun String.hexStringToByteArray(): ByteArray {

        val result = ByteArray(length / 2)

        for (i in 0 until length step 2) {
            val firstIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(this[i]);
            val secondIndex = HEX_CHARS.indexOf(this[i + 1]);

            val octet = firstIndex.shl(4).or(secondIndex)
            result.set(i.shr(1), octet.toByte())
        }

        return result
    }

    fun createTextRecord(language: String, text: String, id: ByteArray): NdefRecord {
        val languageBytes: ByteArray
        val textBytes: ByteArray
        try {
            languageBytes = language.toByteArray(charset("US-ASCII"))
            textBytes = text.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            throw AssertionError(e)
        }

        val recordPayload = ByteArray(1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F) + textBytes.size)

        recordPayload[0] = (languageBytes.size and 0x03F).toByte()
        System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1, languageBytes.size and 0x03F)
        System.arraycopy(
                textBytes,
                0,
                recordPayload,
                1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F),
                textBytes.size
        )

        return NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, id, recordPayload)
    }

    fun fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(array: ByteArray, fixedSize: Int): ByteArray {
        if (array.size == fixedSize) {
            return array
        }

        val start = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte())
        val filledArray = ByteArray(start.size + array.size)
        System.arraycopy(start, 0, filledArray, 0, start.size)
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, filledArray, start.size, array.size)
        return fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(filledArray, fixedSize)
    }
}
```

(Took help from [this](https://github.com/sfomuseum/android-nfc-clock))

The AID used -

```
<aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101"/>
```

---

**EDIT :** NXP TagInfo shows this on reading Tag of device B- [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwKkM.jpg)

**EDIT :** Can this be anything related to NFC TAG B ?

Comment: What are the Android Versions of each device? What App are you reading the emulated Tag's with (If NXP TagInfo App are the settings set to use `enableReaderMode` to do the reading?

Comment: Android versions are 10 and 11 sir. All reader apps and default android reader shows Empty Tag for device B

Comment: NXP TagInfo shows this - [IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-j67xvjvDEt1zxbY5EwmcsDr3XGIRtzD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks, ok both should not have Android beam as that has been reported as getting in the way sometimes of HCE and using `enableReaderMode` should get around that. It just looks like one device is emulating a different card.

Comment: Sir any idea on how to fix the _"one device is emulating a different card"_ issue ? (Basically this thing - `SW=6981: (CE) Command incompatible with file structure. [ISO/IEC 7816-4]`)

Comment: No, but you cold look at the Android open source code for the System NFC service, to see any hint of the problem, but it might be because at the low level the 2 device might be using different NFC chips and one of them has a bug in it.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, iPhone NFC reader apps are reading very well, with NDEF messages.